# Docker Volume - Retain host files when deleted from container

Tags: docker, containers, volumes

I have mounted my USB devices to a docker container using `docker run --privileged -v /dev/bus/usb:/dev/bus/usb -d ubuntu`

Within the container, I would like to delete few files from /dev/bus/usb/

This results in the deletion of files from the host as well, which is not what I want

I would like to delete files from the container, but continue to have them in the host

Is there any way that I can achieve this ?

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are using a shared volume, so when you delete files this action is effective into your container and into the host.

Maybe you can write a little Dockerfile to create an image with a copy of your usb files and not share the volume into the container.

```
FROM ubuntu

COPY /dev/bus/usb /path/for/your/copy
```

After that you can compile your image:

```
docker build -t imagename .
```

And finally launch it:

```
docker run -d imagename
```

Comment: I would want any new USB device connected to my system to be detected by the running container. 
COPY would not let me achieve this.

Comment: That's only possible with a shared volume and when the container modify the data, it will modifes the data into the host too. In my opinion, the real question is: Is docker a solution for your problem ? It seems you use docker as a virtual machine but docker is used to auto deploy and sandbox a process with his dependency and not to execute a virtual machine like virtualbox.